# Importing matplotlib pyplot makes datetime fail (ValueError: unconverted data remains)

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have an issue I don't really know how to address and I would like some advice.

Whenever I import `matplotlib` `pyplot`, `datetime` `strptime()` fails to convert data.

### Minimal code:

**Working version, without matplotlib:**

```
from datetime import datetime
date = "3/14/16, 9:57 AM"
datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')
```

Result:

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 9, 57)
```

**Working if I import matplotlib**

```
import matplotlib
date = "3/14/16, 9:57 AM"
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')
```

result

```
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 14, 9, 57)
```

**Not working with pyplot:**

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot
date = "3/14/16, 9:57 AM"
datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%y, %I:%M %p')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 510, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/_strptime.py", line 346, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: AM
```

### Versions

```
python: Python 3.5.1+
matplotlib: matplotlib (1.5.1)
os: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
```

matplotlib was installed through pip

```
pip: pip 8.1.1 (python 3.5)
```

I'm pretty new to python so my knowledge is quite limited but I guess something might interfere with datetime in pyplot

I know people may not be able to reproduce the issue as I suspect it is specific to my system, but I'd appreciate any insight or idea. I can add more information on the system if necessary. (I don't have an other machine available at the moment to try to reproduce the problem)